# PHP SOAP WSDL How to call soap action with the same method name

Tags: php, soap, wsdl

I have WSDL which returns me function list which is included below

```
[0] => ExternalCacheAccessRsp service(ExternalCacheAccessReq $parameters)
[1] => PingRsp service(PingReq $parameters)
[2] => SystemInfoRsp service(SystemInfoReq $parameters)
[3] => TimeRsp service(TimeReq $parameters)
```

How I can call PingReq function by

> __soapCall()

When I am trying to call __soapCall('service') it returns me first method

> "ExternalCacheAccessReq"

Comment: If you want to use __soapCall, the first parameter of the function is the service function, the second is service parameters. You can call it like `$client->__soapCall('PingReq', $parameters)`.

Comment: Also look at another way to call service functions (below is my answer).

Comment: @CristianBitoi Unfortunately this solution is incorrect. I have message _italic_ Function ("PingReq") is not a valid method for this service _italic_

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answer but both solutions are incorrect for this case.

In the first case Soap returns that I didn't pass attribute "CacheName" which is obligatory for "ExternalCacheAccessRsp" (first method).

In the second solution I have message that method "PingRsp" is not valid. The valid method is "service", but as you see on the top all methods have name "service".

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do this is writing the XML request manually and sending by the method `SoapClient::__doRequest`.

Take a look at my answer here: [stackoverflow.com/a/51099774/6783224](http://stackoverflow.com/a/51099774/6783224)

Answer (score -1):

**Given a SoapClient like:**

```
$serviceUrl = 'your service address';

$client = new SoapClient($serviceUrl, array(
    'trace' => true, 
    'soap_version' => SOAP_1_2, 
    'encoding' => 'UTF-8')
);
```

**You can call your method like:**

```
$client->PingRsp($parameters);
```

Best regards!

Answer (score -1):

Your web service method is overloaded and so you should set the input parameters as specified by `PingReq`. The only way the server can distinguish between which overload you want is by the format and structure of the input parameters. You can examine the WSDL to see what the structure of `PingReq` is.

```
$client = new SoapClient('http://wsdl'); // <-- enter your wsdl url

// set $params as defined by your WSDL for the `PingReq` structure.
$params = array(
    'param1' => 'one',
    'param2' => 'two'
);

$response = $client->service($params);
```