# How to call overloaded wsdl webservice method from php soap client

Tags: php, web-services, soap, wsdl

**Webservice** : http://webservices.dishtv.in/Services/Mobile/Trade/TradeSubscriberInfo.asmx
Overloaded method is GetSubscriberInfoV2 MessageName="GetSubscriberInfoVCLogV2"
My php code is,

```
<?php
$mobileno="01523833622";
$url="http://webservices.dishtv.in/Services/Mobile/Trade/TradeSubscriberInfo.asmx?wsdl";
$client = new SoapClient($url);
$soapHeader = array('UserID' => '47','Password' => 'zZa@#286#@');
$header = new SOAPHeader('http://tempuri.org/', 'AuthenticationHeader', $soapHeader);        
$client ->__setSoapHeaders($header); 
try
{
        $res = $client->GetSubscriberInfoVCLogV2(array('vcNo' => $mobileno, 'mobileNo' => '', 'BizOps' => '1', 'UserID' => '555300', 'UserType' => 'DL' ));
} 
catch(SoapFault $e)
{   
        echo "Invalid No";
        print_r($e);         
}
print_r($res);
?>
```

It gives error GetSubscriberInfoVCLogV2 is not found. I need to get the response of GetSubscriberInfoVCLogV2. Can anyone help me to find the solution.

Comment: check this with print_r($client->__getFunctions()); to see the available function list.

Comment: I have printed this, and got,
    GetExistingAlaCarteList
    GetExistingPackageList
    GetSubscriberInfo
    GetSubscriberInfoV2
    GetSubscriberInfoV2. From this I want to consume last method, which is overloaded method with MessageName="GetSubscriberInfoVCLogV2"

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do this is writing the XML request manually and sending it through the method `SoapClient::__doRequest`.

It would be something like this:

```
$request = <<<'EOT'
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <SOAP-ENV:Envelope
    xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:ns1="http://tempuri.org/">
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
      <ns1:TheMessageNameGoesHere>
        <ns1:param1>$param1</ns1:param1>
        <ns1:param2>$param2</ns1:param2>
        <ns1:param3>$param3</ns1:param3>
      </ns1:TheMessageNameGoesHere>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
  </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
EOT;

$response = $soapClient->__doRequest(
  $request,
  "http://www.exemple.com/path/to/WebService.asmx",
  "http://tempuri.org/TheMessageNameGoesHere",
  SOAP_1_1
);
```

Change "TheMessageNameGoesHere" for the MessageName found in the WebService description page.

The XML structure can also be found in the WebService description page, when you click in the function.

The third parameter of the method `__doRequest` is the SOAP action, and can be found in the WSDL file as an attribute of the tag `<soap:operation>`